# Identity for exponential family of distributions

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-theory, exponential-function, density-function

Consider the following exponential family of distributions:
$$
p(x ; \beta)=\frac{1}{Z(\beta)} \pi(x) \exp (-\beta h(x)), \;\beta \in\left[\beta_{n} ; \beta_{0}\right].
$$
${Z(\beta)}$ -- the normalizing constant. $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I want to prove the following identity:
$$
\log Z\left(\beta_{n}\right)-\log Z\left(\beta_{0}\right)=\int_{\beta_{n}}^{\beta_{0}}\langle h(x)\rangle_{p(x ; \beta)} d \beta,
$$

$\langle h(x)\rangle_{p(x ; \beta)}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(x)p(x ; \beta)dx$ here.

My attempt:

It's clear that $Z\left(\beta_{}\right)=\int \pi(x) \exp (-\beta h(x))dx$, it follows from properties of densities.

So, I need to prove $$
\log Z\left(\beta_{n}\right)-\log Z\left(\beta_{0}\right)=\int_{\beta_{n}}^{\beta_{0}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(x)p(x ; \beta)dx d \beta = \int_{\beta_{n}}^{\beta_{0}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(x) \frac{1}{Z(\beta)} \pi(x) \exp (-\beta h(x)) dx d \beta,
$$
Also I noticed that  $$\frac{\partial (\pi(x) \exp (-\beta h(x)))}{\partial \beta}=-h(x)\pi(x) \exp (-\beta h(x))$$

But I don't understand what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $p(x;\beta)$ resp. that clumsy and misleading $\langle h(x)\rangle_{p(x;\beta)}$ (this is *not* a function of $x$) I am going to use the slightly different notation
$$
p_\beta(x)\quad\text{ and }\quad\langle h,p_\beta\rangle\,.
$$
Since $Z(\beta)$ is the normalizing constant it must satisfy
$$
Z(\beta)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\pi(x)\exp(-\beta h(x))\,dx\,.
$$
Therefore,
$$
Z'(\beta)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}-h(x)\,\pi(x)\exp(-\beta h(x))\,dx=-Z(\beta)\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}h(x)\,p(x;\beta)\,dx=-Z(\beta)\langle h,p_\beta\rangle\,.
$$
It follows that
$$
(\log Z(\beta))'=\frac{Z'(\beta)}{Z(\beta)}=-\langle h,p_\beta\rangle
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\log Z(\beta)-\log Z(\beta_0)=-\int_{\beta_0}^\beta\langle h,p_\beta\rangle\,d\beta\,
$$
which is your formula.

Comment: @J.G. Thanks for the fix !